# X11: frameless resizeable windows

Tags: linux, x11, xlib, xorg

Can I have a frameless but resizeable window in X?

Setting just MWM_DECOR_RESIZEH without the other flags doesn't make it resizeable.

I can resize it myself manually but then I need to scrape for themed mouse cursors which are non-standardized and are also different for each corner and side.

Comment: _...because some Unity dude thought that would be so cool/different from evil M$/Apple, not to mention the standard resize grip is a freaking paper-thin 2px so even if I can't find exactly the right icons the user will thank me for improving his window-resizing experience._

Comment: It's the job for the WM. If you don't like how Unity handles it, write a better WM. 1000 applications that sidestep the WM, each one in its own quirky way, is not what I want on my desktop.

Comment: if you don't like the question, you can ignore it, don't downvote it unless you have a reason -- it's just petty. what I'm asking is possible in Windows and OSX, two platforms with more users than X will ever have and the phenomenon you're describing doesn't happen there.

Comment: case in point: there's a very popular app it's called google chrome which is "sidestepping" the WM this way, and I don't see users complaining that it does it in any "quirky" way. In fact most people consider it a usability improvement to have the tab bar and titlebar combined,

Comment: if you don't understand a need or don't have anything constructive to say, just move on and let other people answer please. X is obscure enough that there's rarely any solutions posted to these questions anyway.

Comment: Chrome uses its own cursors, not themed cursors, which you have tried and rejected as not usable enough. Fortunately, it can also revert to the standard borders and title.

Comment: If you only need wider borders in Unity, there is a way to set wider borders for all windows. So this is a non-issue. If you have other usability improvements in mind, you should say which ones. Anyway, in order to sidestep WM resizing you do need to write your own resizing code, complete with different cursors for all 8 directions. There's no way around this.

Answer (score 0):

There are exactly two ways to resize windows:

1. Leave it to the window manager and be happy. This is recommended way for X. If someone don't like it, he can install another WM that will make it better.
2. Make it by yourself - draw border around window, track the mouse cursor and when the user drags the edges - resize the window in a way you like. In this case you must set the [override-redirect](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/attributes/override-redirect.html) flag of the window and WM will not mess with it.